# How to navigate from notification to specific screen in an android jetpack compose single activity application?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

I want to navigate from a notification action button to a specific screen in my single activity application in compose. Based on [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks) I decided to use deep-link navigation. The problem is that when I click on the notification action button, it restarts my activity before navigating to the expected screen. I don't want my activity to restart if it's opened in the background.

This is how I did it:

### Manifest.xml

Here is what I specified in the application manifest:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".ui.AppActivity"
    android:launchMode="standard"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <data android:scheme="myApp" android:host="screenRoute" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

### Root nav graph

Here is the deep link declaration in my root navigation graph:

```kotlin
composable(
   route = "screenRoute",
   deepLinks = listOf(navDeepLink { uriPattern = "myApp://screenRoute" })
) {
   ComposableScreen()
}
```

### Pending intent

Here is the pending intent I use for the notification action button:

```kotlin
val intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    data = "myApp://screenRoute".toUri()
}

val deepLinkPendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(context).run {
    addNextIntentWithParentStack(intent)
    getPendingIntent(1234, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}
```

I thought that I did something wrong here because I didn't find anything about this restart. So I downloaded the official compose navigation [codelabs](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation#7) that uses deep links (as it's also a single app activity) and it does the same when using deep links from intents, the activity is restarted.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to achieve deep link navigation from notification in single activity app without restarting it ?
2. If not, what's the way of achieving this workflow (opening a specific composable from a notification with no restart) ? Should I send a broadcast from the notification action button and use deep link navigation from within my app ?
3. Is the activity restarting from deep links because it's the main activity (launcher) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### Problems

I see two problems here :

- In the manifest, you haven't set the launch mode to single task `android:launchMode="singleTask"`
- Using TaskStackBuilder will recreate an activity no matter what you do.

#### Possible solution - Handling deeplink yourself

I think that there is multiple solutions for your problem. However, here is one possible solution

##### Update the launch mode

To ensure that you will always have one instance of your app, you need to set the launchMode to singleTask

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".ui.AppActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
         <data android:scheme="myApp" android:host="screenRoute" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

##### Cold and host start

###### Cold start

When your app is not starting yet and you open a deeplink, the app will start and your activity will be created. So, in the onStart method, you will be able to handle the deeplink :

```kotlin
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        intent?.data?.let { /* handle deeplink */ }
        // consume the deeplink
        intent = null

    }
```

###### Hot start

When your app is already running, clicking on a deeplink will bring the app to front and it will trigger an observer with the intent.

```kotlin
setContent {
            DisposableEffect(Unit) {
                val listener = Consumer<Intent> { intent ->
                    // Handle deeplink

                }
                addOnNewIntentListener(listener)
                onDispose { removeOnNewIntentListener(listener) }
            }
        }
```

##### Handling deeplink with VM

In cold start, you are not in a composable scope. To fix this issue, you can use your VM as an event emitter for your view.

```kotlin
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    val event = MutableStateFlow<Event>(Event.None)

    fun handleDeeplink(uri: Uri) {
        event.update { Event.NavigateWithDeeplink(uri) }
    }

    fun consumeEvent() {
        event.update { Event.None }
    }
}
sealed interface Event {
    data class NavigateWithDeeplink(val deeplink: Uri) : Event
    object None : Event
}
```

In the cold start case, call the `handleDeeplink(uri)` method

```kotlin
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        // To handle a cold deeplink intent we need to keep it and replace it with null
        intent?.data?.let { myViewModel.handleDeeplink(it) }
        intent = null
    }
```

In the hot start case, call it too

```kotlin
DisposableEffect(Unit) {
                    val listener = Consumer<Intent> { intent ->
                        intent.data?.let {
                           myViewModel.handleDeeplink(it)
                        }
                    }
                    addOnNewIntentListener(listener)
                    onDispose { removeOnNewIntentListener(listener) }
                }
```

Now, in your main composable, collect the event as state and navigate to deeplink when you receive the event. Don't forget to consume it because we are using stateFlow here.

```kotlin
 val event by myViewModel.event.collectAsState()

                LaunchedEffect(event) {
                    when (val currentEvent = event) {
                        is Event.NavigateWithDeeplink -> navController.navigate(currentEvent.deeplink)
                        Event.None -> Unit
                    }

                    myViewModel.consumeEvent()
                }
```

##### Creating the PendingIntent

Like I said, Using TaskStackBuilder will recreate an activity.
Instead of using it to create a pending intent, you can create it yourself

```kotlin
val routeIntent = Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            MyUri
        ).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        }

        val flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

        val pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            appContext,
            0,
            routeIntent,
            flags
        )
```

Comment: If I don't need cold start handling can I just navigate directly in disposable effect instead of that clownery with viewmodels and events?

Comment: You can do whatever you want to handle the intent in the disposable effect consumer. My exemple shows how to handle it using a VM because it's a pretty normal way to add a stateFlow and dispatch an event to the view